# Создать Grid программно в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно создать Grid размером 12*3 - т.е в длину 12 и в высоту 3
и в каждую ячейку присвоить кнопку
Делал так:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RowDefinitionCollection rd = MainGrid.RowDefinitions;
        ColumnDefinitionCollection cd = MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            rd.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
              cd.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            }

            Button b = new Button();
            b.Name = "Button"+i;

        }
```

В Window_Loaded, в циклах создавал строки и столбцы и кнопки - меня имя созданной кнопки
Но при запуске приложения не появилось вообще ни одной кнопки - это во-первых и

во-вторых как мне теперь через код назначит в цикле каждой кнопке соответствующую ячейку?

MainGrid - имя которое я дал Grid присутствующему на форме

UPD:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            rd.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
              cd.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

                Button b = new Button();
                b.Name = "Button" + j;
                Grid.SetRow(b,j);
                Grid.SetColumn(b, i);
            }



        }
```

- Форма по прежнему пустая

Comment: Если количество строк и столбцов известно заранее, почему бы не создать RowDefinition и ColumnDefinition прямо в XAML'е?

Comment: Вы создаёте кнопки, но никуда их не прикрепляете — откуда Grid про них узнает?

Comment: И создание кнопок стоит делать во втором цыкле если нужно в каждой ячейке по кнопке саздавать.

Comment: Вы создаёте кнопки, но никуда их не прикрепляете — откуда Grid про них узнает? - вот про это я и спрашивал

Comment: Если количество строк и столбцов известно заранее, почему бы не создать RowDefinition и ColumnDefinition прямо в XAML'е?  - ну а если мне допустим нужен Grid 20*20 - все это руками в XAML'е создавать как то не хочится

Comment: Кнопки на форме так и не появляются - хотя перенес их во внутренний цикл

Comment: Можно узнать что вы хотите сделать? Программное создание `Grid` не кажется мне хорошей идеей.

Comment: Хочу сделать "клавиатуру из кнопок" - только пока еще не задумывался над вопросом о том, как на второй и третьей итерации строк генерировать не по 12 а по 11 и 10 кнопок в строке
А"клавиатуру из кнопок" хочу сделать чтобы попрактиковаться в изучении маршутизируемых событий - отлавливая нажатия на  Panel в которой я их предполагаю располагать - что то типа клавиатурного тренажера.
 Конечно если не получится "сгенерировать" именно так как я хочу - буду практиковаться с одной кнопкой

Comment: @BadCats не уверен,что это хорошая практика при изучении маршрутизируемых событий, в данном случае вам совсем не нужно идти тем путем, которым вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит " СОВСЕМ не нужно идти тем путем которым вы хотите реализовать" -  конечно благодарен за совет но, это уже скорее мне решать.

Comment: @BadCats решать безусловно вам и только вам, я просто пытаюсь по мере своих знаний давать советы о том как, на мой взгляд, лучше поступить

Answer (score 2):

```
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.ShowGridLines = true;
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());


        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = "test";
        Grid.SetRow(btn, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(btn, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(btn);

        //и т.д.
        this.Content = grid;
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/cdb450c8-1651-42e3-8ce2-04a673bd9e06/-wpf-c?forum=fordesktopru

Comment: Grid.SetRow(btn, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn, 0); - вот за это спасибо, а то я пытался обращаться к уже существующему Grid а не типу в целом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(50) });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {



                Button b = new Button
                {
                    Name = "Button" + j,
                    Content = "test",
                   Width = 50 
                };
                MainGrid.Children.Add(b);
                Grid.SetRow(b, j);
                Grid.SetColumn(b, i);
            }
        }
    }
```